# Displaying posts with only upcoming dates according their custom field date value

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, meta-query, date

I got posts that have starting date as a custom field value. I'm displaying few of those posts in my sidebar in ascending order so that the post with closest starting date is shown first. This is what I have and it works great:

```
<?php query_posts('&post_type=events&posts_per_page=5&meta_key=start_date&orderby=meta_value&order=asc'); ?><?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?><li><span class="eventtext"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
```

But I was wondering, how could I filter the query so that it won't display posts with their starting dates already gone?

I've experimented with this:

```
$today = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+2 hours'));
      query_posts(array(
      'post_type' => 'events',
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
      'meta_key' => 'start_date',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'meta_query' => array(
         array(
         'key' => 'start_date',
         'meta-value' => $value,
         'value' => 'start_date',
         'compare' => '>=',
         'type' => 'CHAR'
         )
      )
   ));
```

But it doesen't display anything. One thing to note is that the starting date value is saved in mm/dd/yyy -format, but changing the $today's date format haven't helped either.

**UPDATE**

So now I got this:

```
    <?php
$today = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+2 hours'));
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'events',
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
      'meta_key' => 'start_date',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'meta_query' => array(
array(
         'key' => 'start_date',
'meta-value' => 'start_date',
         'value' => $today,
         'compare' => 'DATE',
         'type' => 'CHAR'
))
   ));
?>
```

Nothing shows up in the sidebar.

Note: the date is in that format since the posts are saved with the start_date custom field in that format. I'm just trying to get this work, then I'll change the date format to a more suitable one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work reliably, the date format in the database should be `yyyy-mm-dd`. Comparison type should be `DATE` or `NUMERIC`. If you take the date of 25-04-2012 in present format and compare it numerically to the date 26-04-1986, you can see what the issue will be: 25042012 < 26041986

ALso- if you're doing these queries in addition to your main loop, use a new instance of [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

EDIT-

there were a few errors you didn't fix. note that this *still* won't work quite right until you fix the date format.

```
<?php
$today = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+2 hours'));
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'events',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'meta_key' => 'start_date',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
  array(
    'key' => 'start_date',
    'value' => $today,
    'compare' => '>=',
    'type' => 'DATE'
  ))
));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, great points in using date or numeric instead of >. However, no matter if I use WP-Query or not, I can't get the posts to display. No errors or anything, the sidebar is just empty. Something wrong with my query?

Comment: @Andrew - in your `meta_query`, `'value'` should be `'value' => $today`. `'meta-value'` isn't a valid parameter.

Comment: Still no cigar. Simply nothing appears, very weird.

Comment: @Andrew - have you changed the date format in the database?

Comment: @Andrew - update your question and add the new code you're currently using.

Comment: Updated the question, sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Andrew - see edit.

Comment: It will be easier if you convert your date formats to timestamps when saving the meta fields, and then look for posts that have a "start_date" value greater than time()

Comment: Sorry, I've totally forgot to mark the answer as right. Thank you very much!